# No match for 'operator=='

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-keyword

I've run into entirely unknown error. I have searched for information on the Internet about the error, but the things that come out do not work, the error is in the following line of code:

```
if(opcion==1 && ((*Lista)->PrimerNodo->siguiente)==((*Lista)->UltimoNodo))
```

and the error message I receive is:

```
error: base operand of `->` has non-pointer type `ListaCircular`
```

the *pointer* `*Lista` is the type `ListaCircular`, and `ListaCircular` is a structure built as follows:

```
struct ListaCircular{
    Nodo *PrimerNodo,*UltimoNodo;
    ListaCircular(){
        PrimerNodo->anterior=UltimoNodo;
        PrimerNodo->siguiente=UltimoNodo;
        UltimoNodo->anterior=PrimerNodo;
        UltimoNodo->siguiente=PrimerNodo;
    }
```

`*PrimerNodo` and `*UltimoNodo` are the type node, which is a structure constructed as follows:

```
struct Nodo{
long Cedula,Telefono;
Nodo *siguiente,*anterior;
char* Nombre,Apellido,Correo;

Nodo()
{
  siguiente=anterior=NULL;
}
```

Any idea that could solve the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Lista` is a pointer to `ListaCircular` e.g.:

```
 ListaCircular *Lista = ....
```

then you `if` statement should be like this:

```
 if(opcion==1 && (Lista->PrimerNodo->siguiente)==(Lista->UltimoNodo))
```

The error message is basically telling you that when you dereference `Lista` using `*` the type you are getting back is not a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you should either use (provided Lista the pointer to the list)

```
(*Lista).PrimerNode
```

etc. or

```
Lista->PrimerNodo
```

The error message itself indicates, that there is no `operator ->` defined in your struct. If it were defined, you could also use `(*Lista)->` - if that would make sense. You can also define the operator for `*` by the way.